# css: How to make elements not to overlap + automatically place them in a relevant position

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make a website where users are allowed to post posts, but I have 2 Problems.

- The first one Being that those elements overlap, the elements are
  automatically placed as divs using data from DB, so i wouldn't be
  really giving each one a different id.
- The second one being, how to only allow 3 of them to stay in the same
  line.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you provide and example of the HTML that is output?

Comment: Well, the solution was given but: <div id="box"> Content Given By php </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you structure every div, I recommend you to use CSS Box Model to avoid overlaping of divs

```
    div {
         width: 320px;
         padding: 10px;
         border: 5px solid gray;
         margin: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah that helps with the overlapping part, but it just makes them go down as a list, but i prefer it going like icons, as much as 3 per line.

Comment: Maybe [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) will work for you

      container {
         display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
      }

Comment: My site is not providing ie <9 support so that's fine